# How can I use java ee with JDK11

Tags: java

as we know, JDK 11 has removed Java EE modules, how can use javaee modules with jdk11, some class can't find, eg. javax.xml.bind

Answer (score 0):

The  standalone versions of the Java EE technologies can be accessed   via third-party tools and frameworks such as Maven Central, there is no need for the Java SE Platform or the JDK to include them.